# Remove commandbar ability to expand WP 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I want to remove the ability to expand the command bar. (no dots)

Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it's not possible to remove the ellipsis (those three dots) from application bar.

If you have no *Secondary commands* then ellipsis will just show labels of your app bar buttons. Taking a look at [ClosedDisplayMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar.closeddisplaymode) you have only two values: *minimal* and *compact* - which means that you cannot have app bar opened with labels without ellipsis.

Other way may be to build your own control which will immitate application bar - then you can put there what you want.

Comment: Tried ClosedDisplayMode, but didn't get the effect I wanted.

Comment: What about the guidelines? I don't think it's ok to immitate commandbar. Guess I'll leave the dots there.

Comment: @ErickFilho I concur with what Abdallah Shakhatreh has said.

Answer (score 1):

As Romasz Said it's not possible to remove the three dots. But you can create a template smiler to application bar, something like that :

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >

    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="#FF1F1F1F" >
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"   Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <AppBarButton  x:Name="test1" Icon="Play"/>
            <AppBarButton  x:Name="test2" Icon="ReShare"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

And this will give you :

[image]

Comment: What about the guidelines? Is it ok?

Comment: I think the Windows Phone User accustomed to click on "three dots" to know what the button will do by it's label, and this will be a problem but I think there is nothing against the guidelines using this approach .

Comment: this will be better for your app .